# Include external 'exe' files in electron application - Quasar Framework

Tags: javascript, vue.js, electron, electron-builder, quasar-framework

I'm developing an electron application in Quasar framework. This application has an external dependency (An 'exe' file).

[image: Folder structure of the application]

I am calling these dependencies via **execFileSync** and I got spawn errors while using a relative path. Even though I fixed those by using an absolute path, It would clear some confusion if I could use an relative path.(The services are built and placed into **.quasar** directory but the 'exe' files aren't, this caused the errors).

[image: No exe files present in .quasar folder]

I am using the **electron-builder** package and tried to at least bundle those 'exe' files along with the final build. But the files are not included in the final build.

```
      builder: {
    // https://www.electron.build/configuration/configuration

    appId: "com.company.app",
    extraResources: [
      {
        from: "src-electron/external/printer-handler",
        to: "external/printer-handler",
        filter: ["**/*"],
      },
    ],
  },
```

The above is the builder config I tried.

**TLDR;**

1. Need a way to call these dependencies via a relative path while developing.
2. Need a way to include those dependencies in the final build.